# AngularJs code efficiency mvc framework

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller

I'm just new to AngularJs and haven't understand the whole thing yet, I have a lot of questions and these are the following:

1. I want to hit the code on the controller during onclick only, Is it possible?
2. Or it's impossible since the controller is always loaded when the view loads?
3. What's the best way for me to create a function that will only hit during onclick of the button? And not everytime the page loads. (AngularJs way)

This is my html:

```
<ion-view view-title="Account Fixer">
      <ion-content class="padding">
        <div class="list">
            <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
                <span class="input-label">IrId</span>
                <input type="text" placeholder="irid" value="{{irid}}" disabled>
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
                <span class="input-label">Email</span>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter New Email" value="{{email}}">
            </label>
            <button class="item button button-block button-positive" ng-click="postForm()">Fix Issue</button>
        </div>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
```

This is my controller:

```
.controller('TestCtrl',function(Test,$scope, $http, $stateParams){

$scope.email = Test.get('AB12345').email;
$scope.irid = Test.get('AB12345').irid;

//I want to hit this during onclick ONLY
    $scope.postForm = function(dataForm){

    var encodedString = 'action=' + 
            encodeURIComponent("QA_fixEmail") +
            '&irid=' +
            encodeURIComponent(Acct.acctData().irid) + 
            '&email=' +
            encodeURIComponent(dataForm.email) + 
            '&password=' +
            encodeURIComponent("abcd1234");
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'someservice',
        data: encodedString,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    })
    .success(function(data,status){
        console.log(status);
    })
    .error(function(data, status){
        console.log(status);
    })
}
})
```

Comment: What you've shown so far should work just fine. In what way is it not working?

Comment: It's working, what I want to achieve is, to hit the $scope.postForm ONLY during button click from my html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: Is it possible ... to [hit a function] during onclick only?

A: Yes, of course.  Just use [ngClick](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick)

Here are some examples:

[AngularJS Events](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_events.asp)

Note that one link uses `ng-click`, and the other link uses `ngClick`.  These are equivalent:

[AngularJS, ng-click vs ng:click vs ngClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23703975/angularjs-ng-click-vs-ngclick-vs-ngclick)

Comment: sir paul, but why is it when I place a breakpoint on the code it hits the $scope.postForm = function() even if I didn't click the button  yet

Comment: Because *DEFINIING* a JS function (done when the code is first parsed) is different from *EXECUTING* a function (done only when it's called - e.g. by the click event).  Put your breakpoint *INSIDE* postForm and you should see what I mean.  'Hope that helps :)

Comment: so this means, it only initialized the function? but not necessarily execute did i get your explanation right?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  BTW: your code looks fine, and it looks like you're already familiar with ngClick ;)

Comment: yes i've used ngClick on my other pages. thanks btw, i thought during the hit, it was executing... Thanks!